# FullCalendar Fortnightly Event

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

I can get daily sorted by using

```
  daysOfWeek: [2],
```

I can't find anything in the documentation to make it fortnightly. Is this possible with fullcalendar?

Solution:
For future people, you need the rrule js file loaded otherwise it wont work

Comment: Docs for FullCalendar's RRule plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [rrule](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin)

```
    events: [
    {
      title: 'work',
      rrule: {
        freq: 'weekly',
        interval: 2,
        byweekday: [ 'mo'],
        dtstart: '2022-02-01'
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Sorry didnt work, isnt displaying any event on the calendar with this

Comment: @user9820353 https://codepen.io/rony1235/pen/qBpNMpL

Comment: @user9820353 please check